# How do I select a random element from an ets set in Erlang/Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

I have a large number of processes that I need to keep track of in an ets set, and then randomly select single processes. So I created the set like this:

```
:ets.new(:pid_lookup, [:set, :protected, :named_table])
```

then for argument's sake let's just stick `self()` in it 1000 times:

```
Enum.map 1..1000, fn x -> :ets.insert(:pid_lookup, {x, self()}) end
```

Now I need to select one at random. I know I could just select a random one using `:ets.lookup(:pid_lookup, :rand.uniform(1000))`, but what if I don't know the size of the set (in the above case, 1000) in advance?

How do I find out the size of an ets set? And/or is there a better way to choose a random pid from an ets data structure?

Comment: You could use `:ets.info(tab, :size)` to get the size of the table. I don't really know the best option of grabbing a random element from it though. What is the usecase for grabbing a random pid from the set?

Comment: @JustinWood I'm just benchmarking genservers. I'm creating 1000 of them then I want each to send messages to another random one a bunch of times and see how long it takes with various message sizes. But as I create the Genservers they start so the other genservers might not be up yet when they start sending. So I need to know how many have been created in the initial stages of the benchmark.

Comment: Well the 1000 is arbitrary of course. I'll check out the performance based on various numbers. I essentially want to get a mental map of how fast message passing is.

Comment: If you just want to test message passing, why not spin up all the gen servers and then start sending messages?

Comment: Well I do want to know how to select stuff at random in an ets table for a bunch of statistics work I do anyway. But to answer your question directly, as I spin up the 1000 Genservers, the first ones will start sending before the last ones have spun up. Therefore, I can't just select a random number out of 1000. I need to know how many have been spun up, and for that I need to know what the size of the ETS table.

Comment: @JustinWood please turn ```ets.info(<table name>, :size)``` into an answer and I will proceed to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

- If keys are sequential number

```
tab = :ets.new(:tab, [])
Enum.each(1..1000, & :ets.insert(tab, {&1, :value}))
size = :ets.info(tab,  :size) 
# size = 1000
value_picked_randomly = :ets.lookup(tab, Enum.random(1..1000))
```

`:ets.info(tab, :size)` returns a size of a table; which is a number of records inserted on given table.

- If you don't know that the keys are

```
first = :ets.first(tab)
:ets.lookup(tab, first)
func = fn key->
    if function_that_may_return_true() do
        key = case :ets.next(tab, key) do
         :'$end_of_table' -> throw :reached_end_of_table
         key -> func.(key)
        end
    else 
        :ets.lookup(tab, key)
    end
end
func.()
```

`func` will iterate over the ets table and returns a random value.
This will be time consuming, so it will not be an ideal solution for tables with large number of records.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from the comments, this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

What you essentially need is to track down the changing list and pick up one of its elements randomly. `ETS` in general and `:ets.set` in particular are by no mean intended to be queried for size. They serve different purposes.

Spawn an [`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Agent.html) within your supervision tree, holding the list of PIDs of already started servers and use `Kernel.length/1` to query its size, or even use [`Enum.random/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#random/1) if the list is not *really* huge (the latter traverses the whole enumerable to get a random element.)

Comment: this is a solution only if you are not worried about DDOSing your agent. I specifically avoided solutions involving single-process bottlenecks. 1000 is an example only. The comments further state that I'm benchmarking. It's therefore reasonable to assume that the number to track could become orders of magnitude larger. Hence ETS. Really the question is perfectly clear. I did not ask for someone to second guess my architecture, I simply asked specific questions about ETS namely how to find size, or how to sample randomly.

Comment: I am 102% positive that `Agent` will do fine in that case, but if you insist on using ETS, just keep track of the number is the separate ETS. Upon insertion into PIDs ETS, also increase the counter.